# Getting Http Response code is very slow

Tags: java, http

I am checking the URL redirection for many urls and getting their response code from each url.

I wrote this code but the process is very slow in getting the response code.

Is there any other way so that I can get faster response.

Here is my code:

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL("http://www.someurl.com").openConnection());
con.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
con.connect();
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println(responseCode);
```

Comment: i don't think it  wont depend on your's code.It will depend on the network traffic and net speed

Comment: ping the url from command line and see the response time..